# Кнопки не работают снова после нажатия

Tags: android, kotlin

Код:
MainActivity:

```
tasks.setOnClickListener() { tasks_window.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
home.setOnClickListener() { user_window.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
east.setOnClickListener() { feed_window.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
news.setOnClickListener() { news_window.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
dailybook.setOnClickListener() { dailybook_window.visibility = View.VISIBLE }

requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

if (tasks_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
news_window.visibility = View.GONE
user_window.visibility = View.GONE

if (dailybook_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    tasks_window.visibility = View.GONE
feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
news_window.visibility = View.GONE
user_window.visibility = View.GONE

if (feed_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    tasks_window.visibility = View.GONE
dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
news_window.visibility = View.GONE
user_window.visibility = View.GONE

if (news_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    tasks_window.visibility = View.GONE
feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
user_window.visibility = View.GONE

if (user_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    tasks_window.visibility = View.GONE
feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
news_window.visibility = View.GONE
dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: Я видимо понял с чем это связано, у меня слои которые должны быть видимы стоят по слоям сверху вниз, и не понятно почему тогда не срабатывает условие

Comment: tasks.setOnClickListener()
        {
            tasks_window.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            user_window.visibility = View.GONE
            dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
            feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
            news_window.visibility = View.GONE
        }

Рабочий код

Answer (score 2):

Такое ощущение, что вы пришли из пайтона. В котлине, если нет фигурных скобок, то при верности условия выполнится только следующая за условием строка. Поэтому, все строки, выделенные табуляцией, нужно включать в фигурные скобки.

Рассмотрим первый блок

Вместо этого:

```
if (tasks_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
    feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
    news_window.visibility = View.GONE
    user_window.visibility = View.GONE
```

Нужно сделать так:

```
if (tasks_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
    dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
    feed_window.visibility = View.GONE
    news_window.visibility = View.GONE
    user_window.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Потому-что если условие `if (tasks_window.visibility == View.VISIBLE)` верное, выполнится только следующая строка:

```
dailybook_window.visibility = View.GONE
```

А остальные 3 строки будут выполняться ВСЕГДА!